# Why “which” returns none on some commands I can run?

Tags: bash

I used `which` to tell the location of a runnable file. For example, `which pwd` returns `/bin/pwd`. However, I found `which alias` or `which compgen` etc returns nothing.

What are commands like `alias`? Aren't they executable files on my Linux? I am using bash 4.3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: See [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249) for more than you ever wanted to know about this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> I found `which alias` or `which compgen` etc returns nothing.

Both of those are shell builtins.  `which` knows nothing of shell builtins: it simply searches a path for executables.

For a more reliable result, use `type`.

```
$ type compgen
compgen is a shell builtin
$ type alias
alias is a shell builtin
```

`type` has better knowledge of what executes because it is a shell builtin.

#### Why `which` is unreliable

`which` often gives the wrong answer.  Observe:

```
$ type pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
$ which pwd
/bin/pwd
```

When you run `pwd`, without specifying an explicit path, the shell will execute its builtin, not the executable that `which` found.

Here are more examples of `which` giving the wrong answer:

```
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ which echo
/bin/echo
$ type [
[ is a shell builtin
$ which [
/usr/bin/[
```

Observe:

```
$ type /bin/echo
/bin/echo is /bin/echo
```

When you give an explicit path for `echo`, such as `/bin/echo`, then the shell would run that executable, not its builtin.  `type` knows that also, as you can see above.

#### How `which` works internally

On debian-like systems, `which` is a simple shell script,  The relevant part of which is:

```
   for ELEMENT in $PATH; do
    if [ -z "$ELEMENT" ]; then
     ELEMENT=.
    fi
    if [ -f "$ELEMENT/$PROGRAM" ] && [ -x "$ELEMENT/$PROGRAM" ]; then
     puts "$ELEMENT/$PROGRAM"
     RET=0
     [ "$ALLMATCHES" -eq 1 ] || break
    fi
   done
```

As you can see, it does a simple search along the PATH for an executable file of the name given.

Comment: Interesting. `type` is still a shell builtin.

Comment: Yes,  That is why it can know about other shell builtins.  On most machines, `which` is just a simple script.

Comment: The mention what `which` really does is great. `cat /usr/bin/which`.

Comment: Or just use `cat \`which which\``

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because there is not a program/file called `alias` or `compgen`, etc. They may be just `keywords` that BASH as a language interpreter knows.

You can think BASH is a porgram and `alias` is just a name of method in that program.