# "which alias" and "whereis alias" doesn't return anything

Tags: command-line, alias, coreutils

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.  I am unable to find the alias command.  When I enter `which alias` I get nothing back.  Same with `whereis alias`.

Comment: Related: [Why wouldn't the `which` command work for `cd`? I can't find the executable for `cd` either!](https://askubuntu.com/q/532788/816190) and [Why “which” returns none on some commands I can run?](https://askubuntu.com/q/551254/816190)

Comment: Seeing @Kulfy's comment, I voted to close this as a duplicate of the second question mentioned, not thinking of how my gold [tag:command-line] badge would let me close it instantly. Normally that would be no problem. But I very recently answered the question. Only mods and gold tag badge holders can hammer questions closed, and doing so mere minutes after posting one's own answer is, I think, frowned upon. I apologize for this awkward situation. At this point I'll defer to other people's judgment. *BlindStevie*, I'm willing to reopen this if you (or others) think the closure may be incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`alias` is a shell builtin, so `which` and `whereis` don't find it. To find out what type of command something is, as well as where its executable is located *if it has one* (i.e., if it is an external command), you can use `type`:

```bash
$ type alias
alias is a shell builtin
```

`type` is also a shell builtin:

```bash
$ type type
type is a shell builtin
```

When you run `type` on an external command--one that exists as a separate executable file from your shell--`type` will give you the details about that. For example, `which` is itself an external command:

```bash
$ type which
which is /usr/bin/which
```

Because `which` is an external command, it doesn't know about commands that are provided by your shell, which in Bourne-style shells are the shell builtins and shell keywords.

It also doesn't know about commands that you make yourself as shell functions or aliases. For example:

```bash
$ f() { printf 'Hello, world.\n'; }
$ which f
$ type f
f is a function
f ()
{
    printf 'Hello, world.\n'
}
```

```bash
$ alias g="printf 'Hello, world.\n'"
$ which g
$ type g
g is aliased to `printf 'Hello, world.\n''
```

Furthermore, it is possible to have an external command that is *also* provided as some other kind of command, such as a shell builtin. The external command is then said to be "shadowed" by that other command. Running `which` will show you the external command, even though that's not what will actually run from your shell. For example, Bash provides `printf` as a builtin:

```
$ which printf
/usr/bin/printf
$ type printf
printf is a shell builtin
```

Likewise, an external command can be shadowed by a function or alias. You most likely have an `ls` alias that expands to an invocation of the external command `ls`:

```
$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
```

All Bourne-style shells have a `type` command, which can be used as shown in any of the above examples. Some Bourne-style shells, including Bash, also allow you to pass the `-a` option to `type` so that it shows you *all* the commands of the name you've given. For example:

```
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /usr/bin/ls
ls is /bin/ls
```

The meaning of that output is that when you run `ls` from your shell, it is running an alias which expands to `ls --color=auto`, but if you didn't have that alias (or if you were to remove it), then `ls` would run the executable file `/usr/bin/ls`, and if that didn't exist, then it would run the executable file `/bin/ls`. (On my system, those two executables are actually the same file, accessible through different paths, but the shell doesn't know or care about that.) Your output may vary.

When using Bash or another Bourne-style shell, you should generally use `type`  instead of `which`, as it gives you more reliable information. If, in cases when something is an external command, you prefer to see only the path (i.e., to see output in the style `which` provides), you may want to use `commmand -v` instead of either `type` or `which`. In cases where `which` is correct, `command -v` gives the same output:

```
$ type file
file is /usr/bin/file
$ which file
/usr/bin/file
$ command -v file
/usr/bin/file
```

In cases where `which` is wrong (relative to the actual behavior of the shell you are using), `command -v` still does not mislead you:

```
$ type ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
$ which ls
/usr/bin/ls
$ command -v ls
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

In contrast, even though the `whereis` command doesn't know about anything in your shell, there's no single command that should generally be preferred to `whereis`. The reason is that `whereis` shows you more than just where an external command is located. It tries to also show you where some other important files related to the command are. If this is what you're looking for, you can run both `type` and `whereis` to avoid being mislead. In most cases, running just `type` will tell you what you need to know.

Finally, and regarding the `alias` command you asked about: since `alias` is a shell builtin, it does not have its own manual page. On most Ubuntu systems, running `man alias` has the same effect as running `man bash_builtins`, showing a list of Bash builtins but not giving specific information on any of them.

To get help on shell builtins and shell keywords in Bash, you can use the `help` command, which is itself a shell builtin. `help alias` will show you the help on `alias`; `help help` will show you the help on `help` itself. (See also `help type`.)

You may also find the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/) -- as well as the [Bash manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/bash.1.html), which you can view by running `man bash` -- to be useful. They have sections documenting the various shell builtins and shell keywords.

Comment: Thanks, Eliah.  That cleared things up.  Excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with your shell, are you using bash?

You can not find alias with `which` or `wheris` since it is not a program but a shell function.

Comment: `alias` is a shell builtin rather than a shell function, but besides that this is correct, and indeed this is why `which` and `whereis` don't find it.